# Flutter error after running Flutter Doctor

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-2019

I use flutter to develop windows desktop programs, I installed visual studio 2019 enterprise, fully installed, more than 50G. I just installed the part that can change the path on the D drive. But after executing flutter doctor, why does the following prompt appear?

```
error:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

    [√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.23.0-7.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale zh-CN)
    
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
        ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
    
    [!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.0.0)
    
        X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.
    
    [√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    
    [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    
        X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    
        X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    
    [√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
    
    [√] Connected device (1 available)
    
    ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

That specific error message from `doctor` means that the `vswhere` tool is reporting false for the `isComplete` property. This means there is an issue with your Visual Studio installation (or at least, Microsoft's tooling believes there is).

Answer (score 0):

The complete instruction of *flutter doctor* says you need to download Visual Studio (last stable version) and install it. But is mandatory to select the options bellow for installation:

**Desktop development with C++** with these components:

- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (if there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest)
- C++ CMake tools for Windows
- Windows 10 SDK

After this run flutter doctor again and check the result.